# How to i break up a list (not arraylist) into sublist

Tags: java, list, gps, nmea

If you are here to split a List, here is a copy paste of an answer below.

```
You can try subList from java.util. You can implement what you want from this code:

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("test");
list.add("GPGGA");
list.add("Test");
list.add("TTest");
list.add("TTTest");
list.add("GPRMC");
list.add("tesT");
list.add("tesTT");
list.add("tesTTT");

List<String> gpgga = new ArrayList<String>(list.subList(list.indexOf("GPGGA"),list.indexOf("GPRMC")));
List<String> gprmc = new ArrayList<String>(list.subList(list.indexOf("GPRMC"),list.size()));
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  as there are plenty of questions about splitting lists and javadoc is easily found for [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `subList` from `java.util`. You can implement what you want from this code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("test");
list.add("GPGGA");
list.add("Test");
list.add("TTest");
list.add("TTTest");
list.add("GPRMC");
list.add("tesT");
list.add("tesTT");
list.add("tesTTT");

List<String> gpgga = new ArrayList<String>(list.subList(list.indexOf("GPGGA"),list.indexOf("GPRMC")));
List<String> gprmc = new ArrayList<String>(list.subList(list.indexOf("GPRMC"),list.size()));
```

You are using trying to read its size + 1:

```
List<String> gprmc = new ArrayList<String>(datat.subList(datat.indexOf("$GPRMC"),datat.size()+1));
```

Comment: When I do that, I get an index not found error. See updated post